# Include pdf file with existing bookmarks

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, bookmarks

I need to include several papers (PDF files) in the end of my thesis.
The PDF files already have bookmarks, and my thesis has bookmarks as well.

Is there some way to include the bookmarks of the included PDF files in the thesis, or are the PDF files only inserted as pictures?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Have you read `pdfpages` documentation on this?